# Python cherrypy, get the query_string parsed

Tags: python, parsing, cherrypy

I'm trying to get the query and the data (GET params and the POST params) from a request

```
curl --data "foo=bar&hello=world" "http://localhost:8080/mypath?orange=5&apple=8"
```

.

```
query_string = cherrypy.request.query_string  # 'orange=5&apple=8'
post_data = cherrypy.request.body.params  # {'foo': 'bar', 'hello': 'world'}
```

The post_data is correctly dict formed.
how can i parse the query_string like the post_data?

I was reading at cherrypy doc, and I was seeing this:

> process_query_string()
>
> Parse the query string into Python structures. (Core)

But this is not working, `cherrypy.request.process_query_string()` ais returning `None`

Any ideas?

Comment: Cherrypy will assign query parameters as function arguments. A function like `mypath(orange=None, apple=None)`will have the query string parsed for you

Comment: i'm using
@cherrypy.expose
def default(self, *args, **kwargs):

can i access to the parameters?

Comment: if you stick with kwargs: `kwargs['orange']`

Comment: it's not working:
`query = kwargs['orange']`
`KeyError: 'orange'`

Comment: on path `http://127.0.0.1:8080/mypath?orange=foo` ? Add more code about your exposed class to the question then

Comment: now are working, but how can i get a dict of all query parameters?

Comment: when i pass the get param `"orange=99"` and the post param `"orange=88"` i give: `kwargs['orange']  # ['99', '88']` i doesn't like that, i only want to parse the `query_string` like as `cherrypy.request.body.params`

Comment: `kwargs` (or whatever is your `**`-parameter) is that dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CherryPy uses `cherrypy.lib.httputil.parse_query_string` for populating request.params with GET parameters, you can use it like this:

```
from cherrypy.lib.httputil import parse_query_string
parse_query_string(cherrypy.request.query_string)
```

Which returns the dict with parsed query string parameters.

Answer (score 0):

query = urllib.parse.parse_qs(cherrypy.request.query_string, True)